# Short string too long exception

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am getting a weirdest exception I have seen so far in Java in rabbitmq client and Googling around haven't yield any useful results so I am bringing this to SO :)

Anyone could point me to a possible explanation of this or a fix?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Short string too long; utf-8 encoded length = 830, max = 255.
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ValueWriter.writeShortstr(ValueWriter.java:51) ~[amqp-client-2.8.4.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.MethodArgumentWriter.writeShortstr(MethodArgumentWriter.java:75) ~[amqp-client-2.8.4.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQImpl$Queue$Bind.writeArgumentsTo(AMQImpl.java:1549) ~[amqp-client-2.8.4.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Method.toFrame(Method.java:83) ~[amqp-client-2.8.4.jar:na]
```

Comment: Where is the code responsible for this exception? This issue cause by data length limit exceed.

Comment: Update your protocol and use `LongString` for this string

Comment: Presumably the string is meant to be at most 255 characters, and it's actually 830. "Short string" is saying what it's *expecting* to write - it's not saying that the actual data *is* short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public final void writeShortstr(String str)
    throws IOException
{
    byte [] bytes = str.getBytes("utf-8");
    int length = bytes.length;
    if (length > 255) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Short string too long; utf-8 encoded length = " + length +
            ", max = 255.");
    }
    out.writeByte(bytes.length);
    out.write(bytes);
}
```

Your string is too long.

Comment: I faced the same problem, the routing key I was using was effectiveley too long because I tried to publish the payload in the routing key :)